# Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to create a user login form in ASP.NET webforms using web controls. I get this error in the designer class when I compile the code. The code for the login form is as follows :

```
<form class="cd-form">
    <p class="fieldset">
        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signin-email">Username</label>
        <asp:TextBox class="full-width has-padding has-border" ID="signin-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>

    <p class="fieldset">
        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Password</label>
        <asp:TextBox class="full-width has-padding has-border" ID="signin-password" type="text" placeholder="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Hide</a>
        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>

    <p class="fieldset">
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" checked>
        <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
    </p>

    <p class="fieldset">
      <asp:Button ID="btn_login" runat="server" value="Login" OnClick="btn_login_Click1" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Why am I getting this error?

Edit:

Here's the designer code

```
public partial class main {

        /// <summary>
        /// signin-email control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox signin-email;

        /// <summary>
        /// signin-password control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox signin-password;

        /// <summary>
        /// btn_login control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn_login;
    }
```

Comment: can you add screenshot with errors and error message?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the designer.cs file as well?

Comment: The error is not in your aspx, but in your designer file.

Comment: Remove the `-` from your `ID` properties - they should be regular .net identifiers (where a dash is not allowed).

Comment: I have edited my post to include the designer file

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have now

Comment: Why am I getting so many down votes for my question? :/

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, why you think so? :-)

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba since your question was unclear at first. Now it is clear and you will see up-votes instead of down-votes.

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba Your original question was missing the relevant code from the designer, which made it hard to diagnose. Some users won't have the patience to wait for your to edit and correct the question, or don't believe you will ever do it at all. Whether or not this is reasonable behavior is a different matter.

Comment: @Rotem questions should be judged as is, not what it can be.

Comment: This error is so trivial.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Fair point, though the reasoning behind that ideal is often lost on new users and results in alienation. This discussion is meta anyways.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary it isn't really. It isn't trivial to most users VS actually generates code from the ASPX page and that variables shouldn't comply to HTML but to C#.

Comment: I just didn't think it was important enough to post the designer code. Anyways my question got up voted. It was such a trivial error. Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: It doesn't matter if this error is trivial. Not every developer knows the complete language specification from memory. I certainly dont. This is a totally valid question

Answer (score 4):

Using dashes in variable names is not allowedin C#. You do so by specifying `signin-email` as `ID` for your `asp:TextBox` for example. The auto-generated code will use these values in the C# code.

Rename the fields to use underscores, not dashes.

Comment: this interesting why design generator not escape this somehow :-)

Comment: Variable name collision.

Comment: name collision can happens and with standard names

Comment: I don't think so. Sample? (Or maybe I don't quite understand you)

Comment: when two element with same id, for example. in first comment i mean that designer can change minus char to something another symbol that seems as minus but a valid symbol for identificator. something from special unicode symbols

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91753/discussion-between-grundy-and-patrick-hofman).